# How to label Highcharts tooltip from json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

i am passing data as JSON to highcharts this JSON comes from a java method so i cant change this...so please dont suggest to change JSON format...
my code for highchart is below...

```
var json = [{
    "value": 12,
    "name": "platform1",
    "key": "event4"
}, {
    "value": 10,
    "name": "platform1",
    "key": "event1"
}, {
    "value": 14,
    "name": "platform1",
    "key": "event3"
}, {
    "value": 9,
    "name": "platform1",
    "key": "event2"
}, {
    "value": 13,
    "name": "platform3",
    "key": "event4"
}, {
    "value": 13,
    "name": "platform3",
    "key": "event1"
}];
var processed_json = new Array();
$.map(json, function (obj, i) {
    processed_json.push([obj.key, parseInt(obj.value), obj.name]);
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "category"
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'Branch: <b>' + this.series.name +
                '</b><br/>Platform: ' + this.point.y;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: processed_json
    }]
});
```

i am trying to put platform name on the tooltip as i hover over...but i can not find any way to do that...plus is there any way i can create legends as number of platforms...right now i only have one legend named "Data".

jfiddle can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/QTJb7/

Comment: Can you please create a http://www.jsfiddle.net for us to work with?

Comment: @fizzix here it is... http://jsfiddle.net/QTJb7/

Comment: I am still slightly confused on what you are trying to achieve. Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: @fizzix in the code above...when we hover over columns of chart... we can see Branch: "Data" and Platform: 10 (this.point.y)...what i am trying to do is there in Platform : i want the value "platform" from JSON data i am passing...instead of value i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use object instead of array, in point definition and add paramter in your $.map.

```
$.map(json, function (obj, i) {
    processed_json.push({name: obj.key,y: parseInt(obj.value),customName : obj.name });
});
```

tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return 'Branch: <b>' + this.series.name +
            '</b><br/>Platform: ' + this.point.name + ' <br> name ' + this.point.customName;
    }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTJb7/1/

Comment: super awesome it worked...thanks a lot @Sebastian Bochan. (y)